# Convert Duplicate Entries into Dictionaries: Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a database of about 300 computers and I am trying to figure out which computers do and do not have a particular software.

The issue is: this database lists each piece of software individually, with the duplicated computer name on each one.

Example:

| Computer Name | Software. |
| --- | --- |
| Computer 1 | Windows 7 |
| Computer 1 | Microsoft Edge |
| Computer 2 | Windows 7 |
| Computer 2 | Microsoft Edge |
| Computer 3 | Windows 7 |
| Computer 4 | Windows 10 |
| Computer 4 | Microsoft Edge |

In this example, it is easy to iterate and have Python tell me which computers have Windows 7. You create a simple for loop which returns the value of the computer if it sees Windows 7. But the issue comes when finding out which one does NOT have the software. When I say =! to "Microsoft Edge", I get every single computer because it reads every single line that doesnt say Microsoft Edge.

My idea is.... compile all the duplicated computers into a dictionary with the Keys being the individual computers and the applications in a list. This way I could iterate through dictionaries and get results.

Does anyone have other ideas? Happy to explain more if necessary.

Comment: check pandas "groupby": https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.groupby`, `.filter` out the groups that have "Microsoft Edge" and then use `.unique` to print the computer names. For example:

```py
x = df.groupby("Computer Name").filter(
    lambda x: "Microsoft Edge" not in x.values
)
print(x["Computer Name"].unique())
```

Prints computers which don't have "Microsoft Edge":

```py
['Computer 3']
```

---

Or: using [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```py
mask = df["Software"].eq("Microsoft Edge")
print(np.setdiff1d(df["Computer Name"], df.loc[mask, "Computer Name"]))
```

Prints:

```
['Computer 3']
```

Comment: Im getting all sorts of error when trying to adapt this to my data set. Not sure of the best way to approach it.

Comment: Hey @Andrej, I worked with it some more and it worked perfectly